Why is Clang rejecting this coroutine code?
Here's the code:
#include <generator>
std::generator<int> foo() {
    int i{};
    while (true) {
        co_yield i++;
    }
}

Clang 18.1.8 rejects it with
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../include/c++/14.1.1/generator:612:6: error: no matching function for call to 'operator delete'
  612 |             ::operator delete(__ptr, _M_alloc_size<void>(__sz));
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../include/c++/14.1.1/new:149:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'const std::nothrow_t' for 2nd argument
  149 | void operator delete(void*, const std::nothrow_t&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
      |      ^                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../include/c++/14.1.1/new:158:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'std::align_val_t' for 2nd argument
  158 | void operator delete(void*, std::align_val_t)
      |      ^                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../include/c++/14.1.1/new:185:13: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'void *' for 2nd argument
  185 | inline void operator delete  (void*, void*) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }
      |             ^                        ~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../include/c++/14.1.1/new:135:6: note: candidate function not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
  135 | void operator delete(void*) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
      |      ^               ~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../include/c++/14.1.1/new:160:6: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  160 | void operator delete(void*, std::align_val_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
      |      ^               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


Actually trunk compiles...
Maybe it's worth clarifying what my Clang says of itself:
$ clang++ --version
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin


-fsized-deallocation.

@T.C., yes, that makes it compile... but why??? I've read in the manpage, but I don't really understand what's the relevance here.
